# Returning how many occurrences for records with certain conditions

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have the following table:

[image: TABLE]

If a user subsequently registers to the previous user, a record where column X has the same value as the previous record and which has the same date, then it must return +1 occurrence for the user who registered previously.

Practical example:

> **user1** created a record on **03/11/2022** and in **columnX** he wrote *"random text"*, then **user2** created a record on
> **03/11/2022** and in **columnX** he wrote *"random text"* so **user1 must take an occurrence.**

How can I get the result?

Comment: Ok, think I understand. So show us the PHP code you have currently written to do this

Comment: i don't even know how to start... i guess I need to SELECT all rows and then use a loop to check if I have a "duplicated" entry?

Comment: Well select all that "SELECT userid FROM table WHERE columnx = the_one_you_just_created AND date=NOW() AND userid != this_guys_userid". That should get you all the duplicates (could be more than 1) and then use the userid to update the occurance in the other table

Comment: `occurrence` feels like it you could query for that as needed, you don't need to store it as fact, but I could be wrong.